# Ticker than constantly scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll, ticker, news-ticker

I am using the following code, when the ticker gets to the end of the divs it stops, I need to detect when it gets to the end and then start again..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the plugin with no custom options
$(document).ready(function () {
    var left = 0;
var timer;

function tick() {
  left++;
  $(".ticker").css("margin-left", -left + "px");
  timer = setTimeout(tick, 16);
}

$(".ticker").hover(

  function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  },

  function() {
    setTimeout(tick, 16);
  })

 tick();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean end of the document?

Comment: Basically the ticker scrolls divs across the page horizontally but when it reaches the end of the divs it stops, I need a solution that scrolls continuously...